# pygame my picture wont show up on my window

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

```
import pygame 
import sys
import os
from pygame.locals import *

#Allows for the editing of a window
pygame.init() 
#Sets screen size
window = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600),0,32) 
#Names the window
pygame.display.set_caption("TEST") 
#Types of colors (red,green,blue)
black = (0,0,0) 
blue = (0,0,255)
green = (0,255,0)
yellow = (255,255,0)
red = (255,0,0)
purple = (255,0,255)
lightblue = (0,255,255)
white = (255,255,255)
pink = (255,125,125)

mif="climb.PNG"
mif=pygame.image.load(mif).convert()

#Loop
gameLoop = True 
while gameLoop:
    pygame.display.flip() #must flip the image o the color is visable
    window.blit(mif, (0,0))
    window.fill(black) #used to fill the creen with the certian color variables
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameLoop=False #Allows the user to exit the loop/game

pygame.quit() #quit the pygame interface
exit(0)
```

When I select run my yellow window pops up but no image...
I'm new to pygame and python so maybe I just did something wrong?

Is there a specific place that I should have my image saved to?

I'm running on a windows 8 hp ENVY...

I just want to learn what I'm doing wrong so I don't make the error again. (I should also add that I have tried many different pictures and some where not able to be located.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First fill window with black color `window.fill(black)`,
then put image on it `window.blit(mif, (0,0))`,
and last send it to your graphic card (and on your monitor) `pygame.display.flip()`

```
window.fill(black)
window.blit(mif, (0,0))
pygame.display.flip()
```

If your image is as big as `window` then you don't need to use `fill(black)`.

You can keep image in the same folder with script. Or you can create subfolder only for image to have order in folders.

If you call this folder `images` then you have to add this to filenames `images/climb.PNG`.

BTW: better use `/` than `\` in path because `\n` in path can be interpreted as `ENTER/new line` as in any text.

But the most properly is:

```
import os

filename = os.path.join('images', 'climb.PNG')
```